# Can't access JSON output via URL

Tags: json, wcf, rest

I get the service to respond when going to the URL */Resources/Feeder.svc* on my localhost. However, I can't access */Resources/Feeder.svc/ping*, although I'm using the following code.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFeeder
{
  [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    UriTemplate = "ping")]
  [OperationContract]
  string Ping();
}

public class Feeder : IFeeder { public string Ping() { return "pung"; }
```

I've been trying with and without a bunch of attributes, trying to access the service with and without *svc* etc. Nada. I'm drawing blank.

I've tried to follow [a guide](http://wcftutorial.net/How_To_JSON_Using_WCF.aspx) or [two](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-sec) but I simply can't see what I'm missing.

I'm getting empty hits - no text at all. The error says *400 bad request*. Tells me nothing... What can I do to debug it? Most likely it's something really stupid because I'm tired. Sorry about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your web.config and my guess would be that you probably forgot to edit it. You need to do two things. First of all, declare an endpoint behavior. Second, add a protocol mapping. Like this.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <!-- Addition of protocol mapping -->
  <protocolMapping>
    <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding"/>
  </protocolMapping>
  <!-- End of addition -->
  <behaviors>
    <!-- Addition of endpoint behavior -->
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <webHttp />
      </behavior >
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <!-- End of addition -->
    ...
  </behaviors>
  ...
</system.serviceModel>
```

Also, I don't think you actually need the attribute `OperationContract` if you're using `WebGet`. It's redundant.